# Line 1833: Extra content at the end of the document when opening storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I am getting this error when try to open my storyboard file "Line 1833: Extra content at the end of the document"

I haven't find anything on google regarding this error. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change something into Storybord XML? change the storybord into xml view and check if anythings is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the storyboard file and open in source. Check line 1833 and make sure there isn't misc. text that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Hey i have tried this. there isn't any misc i guess.

Comment: @Priyanka if it still doesnt work, I'm happy to look at it if you're willing to send the storyboard :-)

Comment: git + storyboards is hell

Comment: @Mike I concur :/